# Joining two different queries on the same collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection in mongodb (4.2, if it matters)

```
[
{"a":1,"b":1,"c":1,"d":1},
{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1,"d":8},
{"a":3,"b":1,"c":0,"d":1},
{"a":4,"b":2,"c":1,"d":1},
{"a":5,"b":2,"c":0,"d":1},
{"a":6,"b":3,"c":0,"d":2},
{"a":7,"b":4,"c":1,"d":1},
{"a":8,"b":5,"c":0,"d":4},
{"a":9,"b":6,"c":1,"d":1}
]
```

I am trying to retrieve every record meeting the conditions c=1 and d=1 that also meets the following condition. No other record with value b=1 can have a c value of 1.

The result set should be

```
[
{"a":4,"b":2,"c":1,"d":1},
{"a":7,"b":4,"c":1,"d":1},
{"a":9,"b":6,"c":1,"d":1}
]
```

I'm stumped especially because I want to approach the problem as follows.

(1). find every record with d=1 and c=1 in the original collection.

(2). find the values of b in the original collection where more than one record with c=1 exists.

(3). Remove records from 1 than contain a b value found in 2

In sql I would do the following

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
(SELECT* FROM tbl WHERE c=1 AND d=1) t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT b,SUM(CASE WHEN c=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as c_count
FROM tbl
GROUP BY b) t2
ON t1.b = t2.b
WHERE c_count = 1
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  c = 1
       AND d = 1
       AND b IN (SELECT b
                 FROM   (SELECT b,
                                Sum(CASE
                                      WHEN c = 1 THEN 1
                                      ELSE 0
                                    END) AS c_count
                         FROM   test
                         GROUP  BY b)
                 WHERE  c_count = 1)
```

Is such a thing possible in mongodb? My main difficulty seems to being able to get views to interact with each other

I've looked at $lookup but it doesn't seem like I can perform either of the following SQL-like operations using it, especially since the "right table" of the "join" is a view and not a collection.

I guess my questions are n-fold. How can I get the results I want? Is it possible to do by emulating sql? And more importantly, is it possible to join on or filter a value by the results of an aggregation pipeline on the same collection

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using two queries. The first query will be an aggregation pipeline, to get all the valid `b` values. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$b",
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$c",
                1
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      count: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

This will give the following output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": 4
  }
]
```

This array can be mapped to an array of numbers `[2, 6, 4]`. Using this array you can do:

```
db.collection.find({c: 1, d: 1, b: { $in: [2,4,6] }})
```

[Playground link - 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sZwsX7KoUFi)
[Playground link - 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hSY52bPif72)